# The most precise resistor

Tags: resistors, precision, accuracy

What is the most precise resistor available (measured in terms of ppm drift if
measurements are repeated over time)?

I just want a passive box with two terminals.  The temperature will be kept between 20C and 21C, the humidity will be kept between 45% and 55%. I know
a more precise temperature could be used at the time of measurement, but for this
question, assume I will only use these loose bounds.

Whatever the original resistance is, I just want the resistance to measure the same, as precisely as possible, in a year. This will be used to look at a variety of multimeters and calibrators.

Comment: Aren't there resistor boxes designed to cope with temperature variations?

Comment: You'll need 4 wire measurement to eliminate contact resistance variation

Comment: Read [this paper](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/TN/nbstechnicalnote1458.pdf) from NIST, to start. They discuss a lot of detail that you may want to care about.

Comment: There will be always some uncertainty in the measurement of the resistance so this question doesnt make much sense...

Comment: Buy a resistance standard, not a resistor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go: [Vishay](http://www.vishaypg.com/foil-resistors/hermetically-sealed/)
If you have to ask a price - dont ask.

They do have other products too. Vishay in general is a good starter for further research. Also keep in mind: Vishay is know for their excellent documentation/characterisation on these parts.

They are good at initial precision, ppm/C and more relevant ppm/Time!

Comment: Based on the datasheets. with my 1C temperature variation, the best I could find here gives an expected 2 ppm variation after one year (if I could exactly control the temperature, this would fall to 0.1 ppm).  So, can anyone beat 2 ppm?

Comment: @bobuhito Define your required tolerance first because this is misguided. In 99.99% You can always find better. It only ends when you get to the cutting edge. That is the nature of metrology. For example even with a millohmeter and 100Ohms is not going to detect anything under 10ppm, and even then requires four wire well before you get to that limit. And then there's burn-in.

Comment: @DKNguyen I originally was looking for 1MOhm with better than 1ppm, but tried to leave my question more open, and I am more interested in the technology (which for this Vishay example is "metal film in oil in hermetic seal") than in a particular brand. The 4-terminal vs 2-terminal point is negligible for that large of a resistance, but this is a minor point I think.

Comment: @DKNguyen One key point I wanted to make clear was that I don't need good accuracy to 1MOhm, e.g., 998809 ohms would be fine if it just stays there for one year.

Comment: @bobuhito Metal foil is more stable than metal film (metal films are commodity anyways in all sorts of forms) but that's resistors. I don't know what resistance standards use. They have different concerns. Like some versions of this this are 0.5ppm per year: https://www.instrumart.com/products/42862/wika-cer6000-reference-resistors Temperature and time aren't the only things that can cause change. There's moisture, strain, and other junk.

Answer (score 0):

If you go down the metcal path you will find there are resistance standards that are extremely accurate and they will specify all of the parameters and drift which is then guaranteed. Depending on your pocket book, you could get a primary standard but a secondary would probably be close enough and as long as you maintain calibration you will know exactly where it is.

Depending on preferences and the area of science you are in; calibration at a regular interval is required. This can also change with the age of the equipment. I assume you will be using measuring equipment designed to make kelvin type of measurements. If it only has two leads so not spend the money. My personal lab is maintained to ISO standards and I calibrate on a regular basis with known standards. Since my lab is a private non commercial lab calibration standards are not as rigid as others.

I believe currently ISO 17025 is considered the primary international standard for the competence of testing and calibration laboratories. In practice laboratories small to large use it to assure their customers they operate competently and generate valid results. For example automotive OEMs are required for certification for all there measurements. You can look this up by going to ISO.ORG.